# PHP авторизация

Tags: php, cookie, авторизация, аутентификация, логин

Сайт с анкетами.
Я как понимаю, логика такая:

1. проверить есть ли куки авторизации
   если нет то гость. делаем сессию(для избранного, и чего-нить еще) + куку тоже создаем что б не удалялась

если есть то сравнить со значением из базы данных // вопрос 1- одной строки из random_bytes в 256 символов достаточно для id авторизации(если это вообще так делается)?
пользователь авторизован создаем сессию для удобства // вопрос 2 - зачем нужна сессия? там просто удобнее переменные держать ничего не отправляя пользователю?

гость хочет зайти: сверяем логин пароль, если все норм то выдаем ему куку random_bytes 256 длины.
// вопрос 3 - прошу пояснения, везде пишут что пароли лучше не хранить в открытую в бд, но я так понимаю что обычно хранят.ситуация: БД ~500 чел, которые точно не захотят угонять пароли со мной не контактируют.

вышел - удаляем куку.

если пользователь хочет изменить свои данные, лучше его просить заного ввести пароль?
мне здесь сессия нужна будет просто для добавления в избранное

Comment: Чтобы не путаться, можно забыть для начала про куки, достаточно будет одной куки сессии, которую установит session_start(). При авторизации просто записывать логин или ид пользователя в сессию. Не забывать про session_start(). Выход session_destroy()

Comment: сессия (не только PHP, но и любая ее имплементация) создается удобства и защиты. Вы получаете из куки только идентификатор, а все данные (любой имплементацией) стягиваете в сессию и работаете с сессией. Почему так? Потому, что идентификатор можно привязать еще и к IP. И если его украдут - то с другого IP он сессию не откроет. Открытые пароли и http вместо https - это каменный век. Это даже не обсуждается... Длина идентификатора влияет только на коллизии, для хорошей хеш функции сильно большой роли не играет в первом приближении.